# python-urllib3 conflicts with file from package python-backports-ssl_match_hostname

Tags: python, rhel6

I am trying to run `yum update` in my old RHEL6 instance but I ran into this issue with the package `python-urllib3`

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py from install of python-urllib3-1.18-1.noarch conflicts with file from package python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.pyc from install of python-urllib3-1.18-1.noarch conflicts with file from package python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-5.el6.noarch
```

Any idea what to do to deconflict so that I can install the update?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to deconflict

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname
yum update -y
```